# Ist it possible to address the sibling of an attribute with Xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following xml file (excerpt):

```
<duty_room_txt_Alarm text="Alarm" />
<duty_room_txt_Alarm default="Alarm" />
<duty_room_txt_Alarm maxlength="16" />
<duty_room_txt_Permanent_Failure text="Test" />
<duty_room_txt_Permanent_Failure default="Test" />
<duty_room_txt_Permanent_Failure maxlength="32" />
<duty_room_txt_Temporary_Failure text="Return" />
<duty_room_txt_Temporary_Failure default="Return" />
<duty_room_txt_Temporary_Failure maxlength="32" />
```

....

I need to extract all attributes `text` for translation while at the same time keeping the `maxlength` attribute in mind.

Is there any way to adress the `maxlength` attribute for each `text` attribute? The list has thousands of lines and addressing each element separately is too much hassle.

Anny suggestions are very much appreciated.

Thank you so much. Kind regards, Michael

Comment: Which programming language you are using for parsing this xml?

Comment: I have a translation software that extracts certain elements so that only text that needs to be translated is extracted (via Xpath). In addition you can add lenght restrictions coming from elemenst/attributs. So no transformation but "only" extraction.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the XPath

```
*/@text | */@maxlength
```

The resulting list will contain the attribute values (of both `text` and `maxlength`) in the order they appear in the XML.

For example, using Python:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
content = '''\
<root>
<duty_room_txt_Alarm text="Alarm" />
<duty_room_txt_Alarm default="Alarm" />
<duty_room_txt_Alarm maxlength="16" />
<duty_room_txt_Permanent_Failure text="Test" />
<duty_room_txt_Permanent_Failure default="Test" />
<duty_room_txt_Permanent_Failure maxlength="32" />
<duty_room_txt_Temporary_Failure text="Return" />
<duty_room_txt_Temporary_Failure default="Return" />
<duty_room_txt_Temporary_Failure maxlength="32" />
</root>'''

root = ET.fromstring(content)
print(root.xpath('*/@text | */@maxlength'))
```

prints

```
['Alarm', '16', 'Test', '32', 'Return', '32']
```

---

The format of the XML might be problematic for the software you are using. A workaround might be to rewrite the XML to look more like this:

```
<root>
<duty_room_txt_Alarm text="Alarm" default="Alarm" maxlength="16"/>
<duty_room_txt_Permanent_Failure text="Test" default="Test" maxlength="32"/>
<duty_room_txt_Temporary_Failure text="Return" default="Return" maxlength="32"/>
</root>
```

In Python that could be done like this:

**prog.py:**

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import itertools as IT

content = '''\
<root>
<duty_room_txt_Alarm text="Alarm" />
<duty_room_txt_Alarm default="Alarm" />
<duty_room_txt_Alarm maxlength="16" />
<duty_room_txt_Permanent_Failure text="Test" />
<duty_room_txt_Permanent_Failure default="Test" />
<duty_room_txt_Permanent_Failure maxlength="32" />
<duty_room_txt_Temporary_Failure text="Return" />
<duty_room_txt_Temporary_Failure default="Return" />
<duty_room_txt_Temporary_Failure maxlength="32" />
</root>'''

root = ET.fromstring(content)
for key, group in IT.groupby(root, lambda elt: elt.tag):
    first = next(group)
    parent = first.getparent()
    for elt in group:
        first.attrib.update(elt.attrib)
        parent.remove(elt)
print(ET.tostring(root))
```

Running `python prog.py` prints the re-structured XML (posted above).

Comment: Thanks for that. I will see if I can use that. The idea, however is not to create a new document but only to extract the text attribute and then give the path to the maxlength attribute. The software I am using can then check whether the translation is longer then the contents of the maxlength attribute. Hope I made myself clearer. I let the parser know which elemenst/attributes will be presented for translation refereiing to the Xpath of the maximum allowed lenght. This will then be checked.

Comment: One more thing: For me the problem is that I would proceed something like that: Read the value of the attribute maxlenght of the following sibling-element (?). Is something like that possible at all?

Comment: Do the `text` and `maxlength` attributes always alternate?

Comment: The whole file is 3 identical elements repeated3 times. From the first 'element' I need the 'text' attribute (no problem here: //@text) and the the corresponding 'maxlenght' attribute. Then it starts all over again. Never seen such a file. For me the correct context is a huge problem here since the 'maxlenght' is always different.

Comment: I don't quite follow you. Is there a problem with using `*/@text | */@maxlength`?

Comment: Seems so. I am reading all text attributes with //@text. Then this is my context, I guess. For each of those `text` attributes I need the `maxlenght` attribute. So I have to address the `maxlength` attribute starting from each line with the contents of the `text` attribute. Maybe I need a holiday?:-) Since my parser only reads the lines which are directly adressed and I do not want to "export" the lines. In the end I should have a bilingual file with `text` as the translation and `default` as the source.

Comment: If you are using `//@text` to collect all the text attributes, what is wrong with using `//@maxlength` to collect all the maxlength attributes? Since you know the `text` and `maxlength` attributes alternate, the correspondence between `text` and `maxlength` attributes should be clear and consistent.

Comment: Above you asked how to: *Read the value of the attribute maxlenght of the following sibling-element*. You could do that with `*[@text]/following-sibling::*/@maxlength` but I don't understand why you would need to use that instead of `//@maxlength` since you already know the `text` and `maxlength` attributes alternate.

Comment: You are definetely right, but unfortunately this doesn't work: `//@maxlength` writes the value of the first length for all `text` attributes. So the length always is `16`. I am going crazy. But many, many thanks for trying to help me here.

Comment: Maybe this doesn't work (the following-sibling) because it is the same element and not a sibling?

Comment: The problem seems to revolve around the particular software you are using, what it allows or expects. I think you might need to bring your question to the attention of someone familiar with your software.